# Find $dy/dx$ by Implicit Differentiation: $4\cos x\sin y=1$

Tags: calculus

Implicit Differentiation: Why is $y'$ placed in this position?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

By the chain rule, the derivative of $\sin y$ is $y'\cos y$. It is no different when you have $f(x)=\sin g(x)$ for some function $g$: $f'(x)=g'(x)\cos g(x)$.

So, applying also the product rule,
$$
0=(4\cos x\sin y)'=-4\sin x\sin y+4(\cos x)\cdot y'\cos y
$$
that is,
$$
-\sin x\sin y+y'\cos x\cos y=0
$$
which means
$$
y'=\frac{\sin x\sin y}{\cos x\cos y}=\tan x\tan y
$$
of course when $\cos x\ne0$ (but this is already known) and $\cos y\ne0$.

(Sorry, but I avoid $\frac{d}{dx}$ if I can.)